# Compare dates from a CSV FILE in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file in it 's data as follows name ; date; salario

```
Nome; Data; Salario

JOANNA  1981-04-11  7519.07
LUCIMAR 1958-06-10  819.77
PEDRO   1976-05-11  83.43    
JOAO    1989-03-12  867.5    
CAIO    1954-02-13  88.6   
JULIANA 1958-07-15  884.78    
LUCIMAR 1958-07-15  894.7
```

I need to compare the dates and know the person who was born longer and the person was born more recently however I'm not getting .

I can read the file csv however can not compare dates . Can anyone help me?

```
require 'csv'


CSV.read('file.csv')

CSV.foreach('file.csv') do |row|
   puts  row.inspect
end
```

I already tried to compare dates that way

```
data = Date.new
dataAtual = Date.new
pessoa = Hash.new

CSV.foreach('test.csv') do |row|

  dataAtual =  Date.parse(row[1])

  if  dataAtual > data
    data = dataAtual
  end

pessoa["name"] = row[0]
pessoa["date"] = row[1]

end
```

Thanks for listening

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried?

Comment: Thanks.  Can you please edit the question to include that information?  Everything someone needs to be able to answer your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use commas as delimiters you need to specify it by including the `col_sep` option. Then it's just a matter of parsing and storing the oldest/youngest:

```
oldest = nil
youngest = nil
oldest_dob = Date.new(9999) # 9999-01-01
youngest_dob = Date.new(0)  # 0000-01-01

csv = CSV.read('file.csv', {:col_sep => "\s"})

csv.each do |row|
  date = Date.parse row[1]
  if date < oldest_dob
    oldest = row[0]
    oldest_dob = date
  end
  if date > youngest_dob
    youngest = row[0]
    youngest_dob = date
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Format the csv file properly

```
Nome;Data;Salario

JOANNA ;1981-04-11;7519.07
LUCIMAR;1958-06-10;819.77
PEDRO  ;1976-05-11;83.43    
JOAO   ;1989-03-12;867.5    
CAIO   ;1954-02-13;88.6   
JULIANA;1958-07-15;884.78    
LUCIMAR;1958-07-15;894.7
```

here is the code

```
require 'csv'

# load rows and delete empty? rows    
rows = CSV.read('./file.csv', headers: true, col_sep: ';').delete_if{ |row| row.empty? }

sorted_rows = rows.sort_by{ |row| row['Data'] }
sorted_rows.each{ |row| puts row.inspect }
```

Comment: the CSV file is in the correct format the code above is a sample. Thanks for help. Your code list the all rows of file.

Comment: Note that Nafaa did not convert the date strings to date objects. He was able to skip that step because the date format is year-month-day, with leading zeros.  That is a principal reason for the string formatting of dates in the [iso8601 standard](http://devblog.avdi.org/2009/10/25/iso8601-dates-in-ruby/).

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, that was the reason why this worked. because it will always be comparable in the right way. If instead the dates was without a leading zero, like "1981-4-2" it will not work, because "1981-4-2" is greater than "1981-11-2" as strings, but is not true talking about dates.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert the date string into date objects - they are comparable and can be sorted.

```
2.1.1 :002 > require 'date'
=> true 
2.1.1 :003 > Date.strptime('1981-04-11', '%Y-%m-%d')
 => #<Date: 1981-04-11 ((2444706j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
2.1.1 :004 > Date.strptime('1981-04-11', '%Y-%m-%d') > Date.strptime('1981-04-12', '%Y-%m-%d')
 => false 
2.1.1 :005 > Date.strptime('1981-04-11', '%Y-%m-%d') > Date.strptime('1981-04-10', '%Y-%m-%d')
 => true
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html